# Cannot communicate with global variables in async functions in Flutter

Tags: http, asynchronous, flutter, async-await

I'm working in Flutter and I'm having a problem with communicating with the rest of my program from inside an asynchronous function.  In specific I'm using an http request (which HAS to be an asynchronous function, so that's not an option to do differently) and trying to (after the async has completed) SET a previously instantiated global variable equal to the part of the response from the http request.

In order to try and parse down the issue, I created a minimal-code example from the basic flutter project.

Code Example to follow.

```
String username = 'xxx';
String password = 'xxx';
String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
String url = 'xxx';
String user_phone = '5555555555';
String locationId1 = 'xxx';
String locationId2 = 'xxx';
Map info;



void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Session ID:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$sessionID',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: createSessionID,
        tooltip: 'Create Session ID',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}

Future<void> createSessionID() async {

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
    body: {'user_phone': user_phone, 'locationId1': locationId1, 'locationId2': locationId2},

  );
  info  = jsonDecode(response.body);
  sessionID = info['session_id'];
  print (info['session_id']);
  return info;
}
```

Effectively the issue is that I can PRINT the values to the debug console inside the async function, BUT if I try to set that global Map variable to anything, it is constantly null, and never set.

I've tried setting it as a Future  and returning the variable, but that doesn't change the fact that it's still not being set properly, as it returns a null for some unknown reason.

So in the above example if I change it to a:

```
Future<Map> createTrip() async { 
  <Same Code, but with 

  Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return data;

  > 
}

<void> updateInfo() async {
  info = await createSessionID();
}
```

And then print the values inside info, it still tells me the same thing, that info itself is null.  Ergo it's never being set from inside the asynchronous function.  And I just don't understand why.

Thoughts?  Ideas?

(Edited Twice to add original code, and clear up confusion)

Comment: I'm confused about why flutter won't let you use `await` and return the value through the function. Could you post the code of when you tried to pass the variable through the function and use `await`, thanks

Comment: Updated code so you can see what I'm talking about.  I use the "await" option, but when I type that line of code, flutter gives this error code, "The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'."  But as you can see it IS an async function.

Comment: Okay, well I figured out why it wouldn't let me await in this circumstance, but it still doesn't help me.  I need the updateInfo function to ALSO be asynchronous.  (stupid me for not figuring that part out prior to).  HOWEVER, none of this changes the fact that I CAN print the sessionID to the debug console, but never use it elsewhere in the program.  Why?

Comment: Well while still working on the problem I did discover something else, that apparently I AM setting the variable, but I'm calling it too quickly, and the parts of my program that want the information need it immediately, and I can't tell them to await...  So I'm not entirely sure what to do...  But at least I may have a lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue here, was that I didn't properly understand the concept of a Future.  (And honestly, I probably still don't, lol).

So I thought that if you would await a response, it would automatically change a Future of a variable-type into a variable of the type it was supposed to be.

That...  Doesn't happen.

So instead, you need to communicate with the different parts of your program in a different way.  The solution I eventually used (Likely not the best, but it works, so *shrug* good enough for me) was to use Global variables to store the information, then use getters to set the local variable my program needs equal the global variable that the server-call was used to set.

So an example of this:

```
Map data;  // Set globally, outside the function;

Future<void> createTrip() {
  // Code for server call
  data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return;
}

Map getData () {
  return data;
}
```

Thus, the issue of trying to return a future, and decode it is avoided entirely.  Again, this is likely highly inefficient, I assume there are better ways to do it...  But at least it works, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have everything correct here, you're just not telling Flutter to update the widget now that you've updated the value.

Make sure you call `setState` with your new assignments.

```
Future<void> createSessionID() async {

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
    body: {'user_phone': user_phone, 'locationId1': locationId1, 'locationId2': locationId2},

  );
  info  = jsonDecode(response.body);
  setState(() => sessionID = info['session_id']); // <--------new code
  print (info['session_id']);
  return info;
}
```

Comment: I imagine you're close to correct, (I was able verify that it's just that I need to find some way for the program to update the visible values the moment the Map info variable is no longer null.). However when I try to input your code where you suggested, my system disallows this.  (It says setState not defined) So even though it's a function being called by a stateful widget, it's not stateful?  Weird...

Comment: Managed to figure it out eventually!  Basically I needed to create a function wherein I set a timer.periodic that continuously checks to see if the info variable has been updated yet, and then once it HAS been updated, only THEN do the set-state.  Also the set-state variant I had to use is a little different than your suggestion.  "mapState.setState(()  {}); (mapState as MapSampleState).resetState(); "  (Or something like it)

Comment: @ArthurEKing, the reason setState() is not allowed is because you are using a Stateless Widget. To manage state you must use a Stateful Widget. hope it helps... glad you figured it out though

Comment: Ah, I thought the createSessionID function was inside the _MyHomePageState class (which is a StatefulWidget). You would have needed to move this function into that class to get my suggestion to work. Sorry about that. Glad you figured it out @ArthurEKing

Comment: Either way, thank you both for the assistance!  Even if it wasn't the actual answer to my issue, it led me to the answer, and that's just as good!  lol.